# YouTube v3 API (.NET) - Get URI of newly posted video resource?

Tags: youtube-api

After scouring the v3 API documentation (and using the API explorer), I am not able to determine how to obtain the URI of a newly uploaded video resource (or any video resource).

I am aware that the video's ID is readily available and it is trivial to construct a URI from the ID. For example, I have this extension method:

```
public static Uri GetUri(this Video video)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
                            {
                                Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
                                Host = "youtu.be",
                                Path = video.Id,
                            };

    return uriBuilder.Uri;
```

}

However, it seems strange that the video resource would not include a few different URLs (regular, shortened and embed-able come to mind).

I also recognize I am probably over thinking this because the only volatile part of the URL is the video ID. I guess I could always put the host name in a config file :)

Thoughts and comments are appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the video ID from the upload response once your request is executed.

[YouTube API samples have a great upload example for this](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/dotnet/upload_video.cs).

Once you have the video id, you can construct the full URL as

```
youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}
youtu.be/{video_id}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As mentioned in my question, I was aware that video ID was available. I was looking for a way to obtain the actual full URI for the video on the youtube site. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6Tsrg_EQMw or http://youtu.be/V6Tsrg_EQMw

I believe now that I just have to build these links on my own using the video ID. Is that correct? Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this approach. However, it seems odd that the URIs aren't provided as part of the Video resource. My client shouldn't need out-of-band knowledge to build the address of the Video resource that it just uploaded. Now, I am aware that these URI templates don't change frequently (if at all), but if they did...my app would break. Any comments or thoughts on this subject would be appreciated. Thank you.